# How do I use curl -T/--upload-file with POST in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, file-upload

I'm implementing an integration to an API and according to example in the documentation I need to post a file using `-T/--upload-file`.

```
curl -u "username:password" -0 –X POST -T filename.txt -H "Content-Type: text/plain" "http://url"
```

My solution:

```
$fp = fopen('/home/myFile.txt', 'rb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize('/home/myFile.txt'));
```

The problem however is that CURLOPT_INLINE only works when using PUT, whereas the example is using POST.

I've seen the following solution but I don't think that's what I'm supposed to use since it doesn't seem to be the same thing as `-T`. I don't see any mention of key name in the documentation either.

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file'=>'@/home/myFile.pdf'));
```

Is there a way to do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `--libcurl code.c` to your curl command line you'll see exactly which libcurl options it used, and then you'll see that `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` is what you miss in your solution to emulate that command line. Ie the `CURLOPT_INFILE` approach will assume and default to PUT, but you can override that.